# How to include video tag / mp4 videos in a Jekyll blog

Tags: html, video, jekyll, octopress

I am *not* looking for a way to [link to Youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529859/how-to-include-video-in-jekyll-markdown-blog/12273878#12273878). I want to refer to a *self-hosted mp4 file.*

I already have `{% audio my-file.mp3 %}` working.

I am looking for an equivalent `{% video my-file.mp4 %}`.

If I use `<video ... />` directly, I get an error "Liquid exception: Unknown tag 'video' in my-text.md".

---

**Edit**: I think there is an existing [Octopress plugin](http://octopress.org/docs/plugins/video-tag/). But how do I install this / make it known to Jekyll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the Octopress plugin, just save the [video tag plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imathis/octopress/master/plugins/video_tag.rb) in a `_plugins` folder.