# <video> in Markdown

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

Using `<video>` in my jekyll markdown is parsing as raw text, how can I get `<video>` to work?

```
<div class="row post-image-bg" markdown="1">
    <video width="99%" height="540" autoplay loop muted markdown="1">
        <source src="/images/posts/send-cancel.mp4" type="video/mp4" markdown="1" >
        <source src="/images/posts/send-cancel.webm" type="video/webm" markdown="1">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: See [How to include video tag / mp4 videos in a Jekyll blog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983987/how-to-include-video-tag-mp4-videos-in-a-jekyll-blog)

Comment: What did you call raw text ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel rather than displaying the video, it displays that code block as just text in the browser

Comment: Sorry but, in order to spot your problem, it can be useful to have a github repistory.

Answer (score 4):

## Explanation

You have the `markdown="1"` attribute in every single element, which tells the markdown processor to parse the contents of the element.

Now the contents of the element are indented in a normal HTML style. However, MarkDown parses indentation as.. you guessed it: code blocks. What MarkDown sees is:

```
...
    <video ...>
    ...
    </video>
...
```

Note the four spaces before the `video` tags here. As with [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), these is MarkDown for code blocks.

## Solutions

There are several fixes for this:

### Turn off MarkDown processing locally

Change `markdown="1"` to `markdown="0"`. Or just get rid of it. I'm not sure why you have that attribute **everywhere**.

### Turn off MarkDown parsing for the file

Rename your file from `.md` to `.html`, or any other extension not specified as MarkDown by your `_config.yml`.

### Prevent MarkDown from recognizing it as a code block

Unindent your HTML. I know it looks ugly, but it's the only way to stop MarkDown from recognizing it as "code".

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice the OP had "markdown=1" on all his tags. Good catch. They should definitely be removed. +1

Comment: @Waylan Very strange. Fortunately I tried to enable MarkDown processing in all my tags (through `_config.yml`) and ran into the same problem. If I may ask OP, where did you learn to do that?

Comment: "markdown=1" was introduced to the world in [PHP Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#markdown-attr) as a way to enable processing Markdown text inside raw HTML (as per the original [rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), Markdown text is not processed inside raw HTML). Various other Markdown implementations have adopted that feature over the years. However, it is only necessary when Markdown formatted text is contained inside raw HTML blocks. Otherwise, it is unnecessary or (as in the OP's case) can cause raw HTML to be parsed incorrectly.

Comment: @Waylan Though your comment is quite interesting, I was rather wondering why OP would use `markdown="1"` everywhere in a **Jekyll** page. This is not standard practice at all for Jekyll. I was wondering where OP could have picked up such a convention.