# Can I bring in a custom video iframe into Jekyll markdown blogs?

Tags: iframe, video, customization, markdown, jekyll

I've just started looking into Jekyll for my blog. Is it possible to bring in custom video iframes into blog posts? I use Markdown. Thanks all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to include video in jekyll markdown blog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529859/how-to-include-video-in-jekyll-markdown-blog)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No problem, you can insert an embed code like `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dHHmUF9gs70" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` in a markdown file.

Comment: Cool Guy ! And good luck for your next adventure !  I'll be pleased to help on any question about your next blog.