# Trying to build a Jekyll plugin that adds YouTube thumbnails to links

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have a Jekyll setup that is working out well for me, but I would like to spice up my site by taking YouTube links that are inside their own `<p>` and automatically embed and image inside.

I have figured out the format for YouTube links.

`https://img.youtube.com/vi/<videoid>/0.jpg`

and I have found a regular expression to match the video id inside a YouTube link.

`v=(\w+)">`

I have figured out also I need a `:post-render` hook and I have the plugin set up and running.

I am a bit stuck on what to do next, I am not a ruby expert and I am absolutely terrible at regular expressions.

My algorithm should be something like

1. for each YouTube link
2. find the video id
3. use the video id to make a YouTube thumbnail URL
4. insert YouTube thumbnail URL into the link's `<a>`

it looks like the regular expression functions in ruby want to do everything in one line, so I am not clear on how to approach a multi-step find and replace.

I would appreciate some direction.

Comment: See if this answer contains any helpful tips: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514580/100134

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this approach (this is js though and needs to be ported to ruby):

https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/open-embed/